# C# XNA - Start draw from bottom-center

Tags: c#, xna

Normally XNA start drawing sprite from top-left, but I would like to start draw object from bottom-center, how this could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to specify a different origin in your `SpriteBatch.Draw` calls. The default is 0,0 (top-left). Note that the origin is relative to the sprite, not the screen.

So if your sprite is 64x64, you want to use an origin of 32x64 for bottom center.

e.g. using [this override](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433988.aspx) (MSDN)

```
spriteBatch.Draw (
         texture,
         position,
         sourceRectangle,
         color,
         rotation,
         new Vector2(32, 64), // origin
         scale,
         effects,
         layerDepth
)
```

You can calculate these on the fly if you wish. e.g if you're using the full texture you could specify it as `new Vector2(texture.Center.X, texture.Height)`. Or alternatively you could base it on the `sourceRectangle` if you're using a sprite sheet.

You need to specify a bunch of other arguments to use these `Draw` overrides but you can just pass in the defaults. The defaults are:

```
sourceRectangle: null = full texture
color: Color.White = default color (sprite colors will be used)
rotation: 0f = no rotation
scale: 1f = default scale
efects: SpriteEffects.None = no flipping
layerDepth: 0 = default layer
```

Comment: Ah thanks, I totally forgot about this, helps alot as I do alot math for the coordinates already

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you are drawing an image `Width`x`Height` on position `X`x`Y`.

```
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);
```

**First** let's set the bottom of the image to those coordinates by subtracting images height from position's Y coordinate (*subtracting because in XNA the Y-axis is inverted, not like in your math class*)

```
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position + new Vector2(0, -texture.Height), Color.White);
```

**Second**, let's set the image to the left by subtracting half of the image's width from position's X coordinate.

```
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position + new Vector2(-texture.Width/2, -texture.Height), Color.White);
```

And there you have it.

**Edit:** Another thought: you can create new variable called `DrawPosition` and use that variable when needed, instead of always substracting. That would look something like this:

```
private Texture2D texture;
public Vector2 position;
public Vector2 DrawPosition
{ get { return position + new Vector2(-texture.Width/2, -texture.Height); } }

public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{ spriteBatch.Draw(texture, DrawPosition, Color.White); }
```

Or, if this new variable doesn't make sense to you, create a function that will return the `DrawPosition()`

```
public Vector2 DrawPosition()
{ return position + new Vector2(-texture.Width/2, -texture.Height); }
```

Comment: It might be easier, but when you create new variable like *DrawPosition*, you won't have any problem knowing both the real position or the draw position. This makes your *spriteBatch.Draw* function simpler, and keeps things simpler in the long run. That's my expirience with origin parameter vs create new variable. +1 for @Tone